# Split String With Letters And Number Groups

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to pull apart tech acronyms for a quiz app

```
Array.from('CAPTCHA')  
    Gives me: ['C','A','P','T','C','H','A']
```

Works great if the acronym is only letters

But...

```
Array.from('AES256')  
    Gives me: ['A', 'E', 'S', '2', '5', '6']
```

I would like to keep any number groups in the acronym together

```
e.g. ['A', 'E', 'S', '256']
```

Any suggestions on how to get this done?
regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/KIAiHJ/2) with [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```js
const pattern = /[^0-9]|[0-9]+/g

console.log('CAPTCHA'.match(pattern))
console.log('AES256'.match(pattern))
```

Comment: That is perfect, Thanks!